# Can references replace pointers?

Tags: c++, linked-list

More specifically, I am wondering why we use pointers in a typical linked list implementation. Are there any problems that the following implementation of a Node might cause?

```
template <typename T>
class Node {
    T data;
    Node<T>& next;
    Node<T>& prev;
};
```

Is there some reason we should use pointers here instead of references?

Comment: What if the next or previous node isn't?

Comment: This list implementation works great on my Turing machine.

Comment: A reference can't be null, so you'd need some way of representing invalid/nonexistent 'next' and/or 'prev'.

Comment: That would work if you wanted an infinite list :P

Comment: Theoretically could you not just make a constant null node to point to at the end of the list? Not suggesting this is a good idea, mind you!

Comment: @DanielBuckmaster: What would the `prev` and `next` nodes of the null node refer to?

Comment: @CharlesBailey In the same theoretical universe of poor ideas, you could make them point to the constant null node and do a `if (next == this)` check. Vaguely similar to std collection `begin` and `end` iterators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set references after creating them, which makes a non-mutable linked-list implementation somewhat tricky. (You'd need to wrap the references in objects that you can re-crate when you want to change the reference).

There's also no way to set a NULL value on a reference, so representing the ends of your list would require some imagination.

Probably better to stick to pointers in a linked list, or even better, use `std::list<>`.

Comment: Or better still, don't use a linked list at all, unless you're just trying to learn how pointers work...

Answer (score 1):

Lvalue references can't replace pointers; they do different things.

An lvalue reference must be initialized with an lvalue and the lvalue reference will refer to that object for the rest of it's lifetime. It cannot be rebound. This presents two immediate problems for your list node.

How do you start the list? You want to construct a node that has no "previous" yet the `prev` member must be initialized with a `Node` object. You could conceivably use a `Node` whose `prev` is it self to represent the head of a list, but this is working around the poor choice of lvalue reference. (E.g. `Node<T> emptylist = { T(), emptylist, emptylist }; //eurgh`)

Second, how do you manipulate the list? You can't change the bindings of `next` and `prev` meaning that the only way to alter the list would be to construct a completely new set of nodes and copy every single `data` element.

Comment: "A reference must be initialized with an lvalue" -- well... not really. `int const& cr = 5; int&& rv = 5;`